# How do I restore databases and website files from external drive to local Ubuntu XAMPP installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp

I'm trying to restore the databases and files from a previous Ubuntu XAMPP installation which is now on an external hard drive to a new Ubuntu XAMPP installation. I have tried it previously but the MYSQL keeps crashing and all other tutorials are for Windows.

Comment: Are you sure this is XAMPP specific?

Comment: Yes I have installed XAMPP so Xampp specific advice would be best